# I have a JAVA Springboot error @RequestParam("")

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I am new to JAVA Springboot and I have an error when trying to send a json by GET.

For the tests I use POSTMAN and this error sends me:

```
{
"status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"message": "Required request parameter 'tags' for method parameter type List is not present"
}
```

json to prove:

```
 "tags": [
  "potable",
  "contaminada",
  "tratada"
]
```

The layers are quite simple:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<PropuestaEntity>> SearchTags(@RequestParam("tags") List<String> tag) {
    List<PropuestaEntity> propuesta = propuestaServices.SearchTags(tag);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(propuesta);
}
```

Services:

```
public List<PropuestaEntity> SearchTags(List<String> tag) {
    return propuestaRepository.findByTags(tag);
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface PropuestaRepository extends MongoRepository<PropuestaEntity, Integer> {
 List<PropuestaEntity> findByTags(List<String> tag);
}
```

Data in mongobd:

```
{
  "titulo": "Análisis de la calidad del agua en el río X sdauiyuadiossd",
  "tags": ["agua", "calidad", "contaminación", "metales pesados", "nutrientes"],
  "estadoPropuesta":1
}
```

The main objective is to search for Proposals (English) by the tags that were previously assigned to them and list all the proposals containing those tags.

Comment: The error "Required request parameter 'tags' for method parameter type List is not present" is very self-explaining: You did not provide it in your GET call.

Comment: I understand that it looks simple but it is not that simple for me. I have searched and I have not been able to send that json to get the results I need, I get that error constantly.

Comment: If you want to have your request parameter `tags` as optional, then you need `@RequestParam(name="tags", required = false)`

Comment: I already did it, it does not generate an error but it does not find the data, which in itself is quite populated.

Comment: That is a completely pther question than the error you posted. And it makes me assume, that you do _not_ want to have that request parameter optional.

Comment: data is:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "titulo": "Análisis de la calidad del agua en el río X sdauiyuadiossd",
        "autor": "Juan",
        "tags": [
            "agua",
            "calidad",
            "contaminación",
            "metales pesados",
            "nutrientes"
        ],
        "recursosNecesarios": "Reactivo de nitrato, reactivo de fosfato, reactivo de metales pesados",
        "estadoPropuesta": 1
    }
]

Comment: "I have not been able to send that json to get the results I need" => What does "sending that json" mean for you? You are talking about a GET call with a query parameter `tags` that you did not provide. There is no JSON involved in the request. What else do you need to know?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the code is quite clear and the error I get is that. I have searched for this same error but have not found solutions. maybe I'm missing something and it must be simple but even my eyes do not see it.

Comment: check this img and tell me https://ibb.co/X72LKMT (https://imgbb.com/)

Comment: now an image without required = false
https://ibb.co/4P7gfdx

Comment: What shall I tell you, that was not already told? In your screenshot the URL is `http://localhost:8080/propuesta/search`. There is no query parameter `tags` in it, isn't it?

Comment: Besides that: GET requests usually do not have a body. You seem to think that a request parameter must be provided in the body. No, it is a query paremeter in the URL.

Comment: localhost:8080/propuesta/search?tags=agua,contaminada it should not be like this? i dont get it yet my friend

Comment: @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PropuestaEntity>> searchByTags(@RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> body) {
        List<String> tags = body.get("tags");
        List<PropuestaEntity> propuestas = propuestaServices.SearchTags(tags);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(propuestas);
    }

its work, in repository FindbyTagsIn(list<>, tags)

Thanks @Seelenvirtuose

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by "JSON to prove", but from the formatting it seems that you are presenting a request payload. In order to prove anything, you would need to show the whole request (including full request URL and payload).

If you send the `tags` via request body, you need to change the annotation in your controller to look for the `tags` in the request payload:

```java
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<PropuestaEntity>> SearchTags(@RequestBody List<String> tag) {
    List<PropuestaEntity> propuesta = propuestaServices.SearchTags(tag);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(propuesta);
}
```

In this case, your payload should look like this so it can be matched to the `List` type in the controller method:

```json
[
  "potable",
  "contaminada",
  "tratada"
]
```

If you really wanted to use the `@RequestParam` annotation, you would have to include the tags as query params in the URL like this:

```
https://your-service.com/search?tags=potable&tags=contaminada&tags=tratada
```